# How to resolve Javascript error "Type is Undefined"?

Tags: jquery

Hi All 
Please tell me how to resolve Javascript Error 'Type' is undefined in 'MicrosoftMvcAjax.js'

Please help.

Comment: Please post the code you are using. It's not possible to identify the problem otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to see at least some your code before we can be sure of giving a good answer; it could be a simple typo in your code. But assuming it isn't, my guess would be that you're trying to run this JS code on page load, before the MS library has been loaded, so it's throwing the error because you're referencing an object in the library which Javascript doesn't yet know about.

If that is the case, you'll need to defer this bit of code from running until the library is loaded. There should be a standard way of doing this specified by the library.

Comment: Thanks Spudley. Your assumption was correct. I added MicrosoftAjax.js also and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you want `type`, not `Type` - remember that JavaScript is case-sensetive.

Comment: Its Capital 'Type'. The errors are in MicrosoftMvcAjax.js and other Mvc related .js files .

Comment: Its Capital 'Type'. The errors are in MicrosoftMvcAjax.js and other Mvc related .js files .Please Help